# Multiple HTTP request safe Multithreaded Spring boot server

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, static

In Spring boot server, my Rest controller class is Multithreaded and many threads share (read and write) a variable for the same HTTP Request. The program is thread-safe for 1 HTTP Request.

But I have some static variables in the program which I use to share information between Java threads of the same HTTP request.

I understand that this would create an issue when Multiple HTTP Requests arrive together.

How should I make the program/server accept multiple HTTP requests simultaneously and yet not mess up the variables 'logger' ,'abc', 'xyz' for 2 different HTTP Requests?

How must one declare and use these variables?

```
    @RestController 

public class ABC {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ABC.class);
private static volatile byte[] abc = null;
static volatile boolean xyz = "true"


// Multithreaded program where multiple threads read and write 
   both 'abc'  and 'xyz'
```

Comment: “_I have some static variables in the program which I use to share information between Java threads of the same HTTP request_” - WHY? You are using Spring, so **use** Spring - this is what the Request Scope is for!

Comment: I don't believe there is ever a good reason for a RestController to hold state. Please elaborate on what the information is that you think should be shared and not "messed up" by multiple threads.

Comment: many threads share (read and write) a variable for the same HTTP Request? Isn't it one thread for one request?

Comment: @LucasRoss I don't want the RestController to hold state. The static variables 'abc' and 'xyz' are infact some variables which the multiple java threads share for the same HTTP request.

Why I chose those variables 'abc' and 'xyz' to be static?  Because I don't know which thread will write that variable and when it will be written. But as soon as it is written- I want the other threads to know.

Comment: The usual meaning of "holding state" is what you are describing: writing to a variable so that something else can get the updated value. As other answers have pointed out, it is anti-pattern with Spring MVC and most other models to hold state in a controller bean. Typically you use databases, sessions, request scope, and other things for state handling.

Comment: @LucasRoss So is there a way I can avoid using a database or a static variables and still share information between the Java threads?

To share information between the Java threads, so that any thread can write that variable and also read the latest value of the variable, I am currently trying to pass the variable (i.e reference to the variable) in the constructor of the thread when it is spawned. This does not seem to work.

Is there a way to share information between the Java threads without using static variables?

Answer (score 2):

The standard HTTP model is one thread per request.

The new reactive model uses Netty and an event bus.

You know full well that shared, mutable data is a problem for multi-thread access.  You'll have to write your code so it's thread safe.  Use the `java.util.concurrent` package.

You make a mistake to deviate from the model of choice.  Smart people have a hard time writing multi-threaded code that's correct.

Comment: Worth mentioning that Spring has specific techniques to handle this transparently - notably the Request Scope.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has some feature to help dealing with that, but it's hard to suggest as you haven't shared your use case...
To solve this particular problem you can use also AtomicReference's, which does not use locks.
Here's a good tutorial on how to use it:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/atomicreference.html